# Set input range using only try/except

Tags: python, range, try-except

I am very new to coding and seem to have mine working but I need it to pick up values over 10 as an error. I've got no clue how to do it without using conditional structures `(if etc)` or repetitive `(for, while)`

```
while True:
 try:
    value = int(input("Enter an integer between 1 and 10: "))
    reciprocal = 1 / value
    print("The Reciprocal of your number is ", reciprocal, "\n")

except ValueError:
    print("You did not enter an integer!!!\nPlease, try again.\n")
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Oops, you entered zero.\nPlease, try again. \n")
```

Comment: You can't do it without using conditionals.

Comment: `try` is used specifically to handle errors, not check conditions. You could use `assert`  in place of `if`, mixed with `try` to catch the raised `AssertionError`, but that would be an awful way of going about it.

Comment: That's not correct @SuperStormer - think about math.log(n, 10) even though it gets really ugly ...